# How can i set hour and minute in time select on 1 input field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, time-select

I want to set my time select like this [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmC7j.png)

I used `= course_form.input :start_at, label: false` and html show hour select in 1 input field and minute in another input field.

Answer (score 2):

check the [datetime select api](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/datetime_select)..

```
starts_at is datetime field
##migration file
t.datetime :starts_at
```

Simple code snippet can be like this with multiple configurations:-

```
<div class="form_group">
   <label>Start time:</label></br>
      <%= f.datetime_select :starts_at , :class=>"form-control",:start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => Date.current.year,:selected=> Date.today, :order=> [:day, :month, :year],:start_year=> Time.now.year,:default=> 1.days.from_now,:prompt=> {day: 'Choose day', month: 'Choose month', year: 'Choose year'},:placeholder=>"Enter start time",:required=>true %>
</div>
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use one of the `timepickers`. https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/